Alternative proof that there is no natural number between two consecutive natural numbers.
First the book defines the reals as a set with two operations that satisfy the field and order axioms. Then, a  set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is said to be inductive if $1 \in S$ and if $x \in S \implies (x+1) \in S$. Then the natural numbers are defined as the intersection of all inductive subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. To show that there is no $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there is $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n < k < n+1$, the books suggests showing that the set $A_n \cup B_n$ is inductive where $A_n = \{ x \in \mathbb{N} | x \leq n \}$ and $B_n = \{ x \in \mathbb{N} | x \geq n+1 \}$. And this would indeed prove the desired result, I did it by induction.
I was  wondering, couldn't this be a lot easier? and I thought, first we observe that the natural numbers must be exactly $1$ and its successors, this is because the set of $1$ and its successors form an inductive set thus $\mathbb{N} \subseteq\{1, 2, 3, ... \}$ and also $1$ and its successors belong on every inductive set therefore $\{1, 2, 3, ... \} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. From here notice that if $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ then $n < m$ iff $m$ is a higher succesor of $1$ than $n$. Then suppose for contradiction that $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n < k < n+1$. Then $k$ is a higher successor of $1$ than $n$, that is, it is $n$ plus $1$ added a certain amount of times, but the least amount of times we can add $1$ is one and $k$ is a lesser succesor of $1$ than $n+1$, a contradiction.
Is this proof good? If not, then what is it lacking? I feel like there's no need to do anything overly formal to prove this result, once you prove that the intersection of all inductive sets must be $1$ and its successors, then the theorem should be pretty obvious I feel like, but maybe I am missing something and we do need more elaborate proofs for some reason, what do you think?

Which book? Which "field and order axioms"?

@AnneBauval The book is not available in English. The field axioms are: Associativity, commutativity, Existence of neutral, existence of inverse for multiplication and addition (except for the multiplicative inverse of $0$) and lastly distributivity of multiplication with respect to addition. The order axioms are: There exists $\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^+ \implies (x + y \in \mathbb{R}^+ \land xy \in \mathbb{R}^+)$ and for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ one and only one of the following 3 are true: $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ or $x = 0$ or $-x \in \mathbb{R}^+$

Thank you very much for this detailed answer to my 2nd question. So, this wasn't a definition of $\Bbb R$ but of any ordered field. (Happily, it doesn't matter.)

This is just the definition of "consecutive" , if there were a natural number $n$ with $a<n<b$ , we would have $b-a\ge 2$ , so $a$ and $b$ cannot be consecutive. This is so obvious that I would consider it as an axiom.

The argument isn't valid because it's confusing heuristic thinking with rigorous proof. More precisely, “higher successor” has not been mathematically defined.

If “$m$ is a higher successor of $1$ than $n$“ is intended to be a synonym for “$m>n$”, then the statement needing proof has simply been restated, not proved.
On the other hand, if “$m$ is a higher successor of $1$ than $n$“ is intended to refer to unbounded repeated iteration of the successor operation (which itself is hard to refer to within the mathematical system itself), then the equivalence of “$m$ is a higher successor of $1$ than $n$“ with “$m>n$” has not been proved and in fact is equivalent to the statement needing proof.


By higher successor I mean it is the result of adding $1$ to itself a bigger number of times. I skipped details, but the proof goes like this: If $m$ is a higher successor of $1$ than $n$ then $m-n$ can be written as $1+1...+1-1-1...-1$, but since the number of $1$s is bigger than the number of $-1$s, then $m-n$ is clearly positive and by the definition of $>$ provided by the book, this means $m>n$. The converse is clearly true as well, suppose $m > n$ then m cannot be a lesser or equal successor otherwise by the previous statement we would have $m \leq n$, a contradiction.

Unfortunately, in my view, this is not formal reasoning (when studying mathematical foundations at the level indicated by the OP). Even the expression $1+1+\cdots+1$ itself, with an indeterminate number of $1$s, is not formally defined in the system. If you think I'm wrong, try rendering your argument using the notation, axioms, and rules of inference used by the book (and any proven results up to that point), but without allowing yourself to use other types of statements or reasoning.

You're right, the book never uses the "..." notation, even when defining $\sum$ they do so recursively. I guess I could try and use a similar argument using sigma notation, but then I would need to somehow capture the fact that for $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $m > n$ iff $m-n \in \mathbb{N}$, and this would probably require a similar type of argument to the one I had to use of proving that $A_n \cup B_n$ is inductive.
